# flutter app crashes after installing on iphone

Tags: flutter, dart, ios14

I have an iphone 11 with iOS-14 and flutter version is 1.22.0 and also Xcode version is 12.

I built my flutter app on my phone in debug mode and it works just fine, however, after i disconnect my phone from the laptop and close my application, later when i wanna open it on my phone like any other app it crashes and doesn't open, before this when i had an earlier version of flutter and Xcode and iOS, it would work offline and after it was disconnected as well. why is this happening now?

Comment: Same issue here - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60657

Answer (score 14):

It is a known bug like Vince said. To work arround it, just run your app in release mode with the following command: flutter run --release.
Your app will then work fine even after disconnecting.

Comment: fcm push notificaions doesnt work in release mode, do you know why?

Comment: Check for your APNs environment, it would be on development & you might be using production one, the best one is to test your notification on TestFlight, or get an development config for APNs.